# Isometry in Euclidean space, matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a few questions about a proof of this theorem:

$f: U \rightarrow U$, $U$ is a Euclidean space, is an isometry $\iff$ there exists an orthonormal basis in which the matrix of $f$ (let's call it $A$) has blocks $\left[\begin{array}{cc}
cos \varphi & -sin \varphi\\sin \varphi & cos \varphi\\\end{array}\right]$ , $\left[\begin{array}{cc}1\end{array}\right]$ ,$\left[\begin{array}{cc}-1\end{array}\right]$ along the diagonal and the rest of the entries are $0$s.

Proof:

$"\Leftarrow"$ is easy, because then $|\det A| =1 $ and that means that $A^TA=I$, so $f$ is an isometry.

$"\Rightarrow"$ If $f$ has a real eigenvalue $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, then we must have $|\lambda|=1$ and if we consider this subspace: $P=<u>$, the matrix will indeed have $1, -1$ for basis vectors which are generated by eigenvectors for real $\lambda$s (Is that true? Does my reasoning make any sense?)

If $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, then we consider subspace generated by its eigenvector $P=<p,q>$ and we choose an orthonormal basis for this subspace. In this basis $f|_{P}$ has a matrix $\left[\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\c & d\\\end{array}\right]$.

(Now, could you tell me how to quickly justify that $f|_{P}$ is still an isometry?)

Since $f|_{P}$ is still an isometry, $B^TB =I$, which means that

$B^TB = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
a & c\\b & d\\\end{array}\right] \cdot \left[\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\c & d\\\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
a^2+c^2 & ab+cd\\ab + cd &b^2 +d^2\\\end{array}\right]$ and we conclude (which is quite clear to me) that $B=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
cos \varphi & -sin \varphi\\sin \varphi & cos \varphi\\\end{array}\right] $ for a certain $\varphi \in \mathbb{R}$.

Next we show that $f(P^{\perp}) \subset P^{\perp})$ and use induction.

We take an orthonormal basis with the right matrix for $P^{\perp})$ (this means the matrix  as in the thesis?). The union of bases of $P$ and $P^{\perp})$ is an orthonormal basis and since $U=P + P^{\perp}$ we get the block matrix.

Can we find a basis in which a given isometry is a rotation?
How to prove that each orientation preserving isometry has the above $\sin, \cos$ matrix in a certain positively oriented basis?

Could you answer my questions in the brackets?

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't get the part involving determinant in "$\Leftarrow$". You should just check that $A^{\top}A=I$.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I guess that's clearer. Thanks :)

Comment: Regarding the question why $f|_{P}$ is still an isometry: all that happened is you change your coordinate system and make a restriction. Isometry is about whether the length get changed or not. So just merely changing the coordinate does not affect anything.